# How to get same name results first in search list iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, nspredicate

[image]

Hello everyone I need your help. I want that like in image if I search carrot listing should show Carrot first like the element having same name show first and if element contains these text list after that is that possible

```
 NSString *predicateString;

            NSString * tempString;

            if (string.length > 0) {
                tempString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",textField.text, string];
            } else {
                tempString = [textField.text substringToIndex:[textField.text length] - 1];
            }

                predicateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELF.title contains [cd] \"%@\" ", tempString];

            NSLog(@"Ingredent Array  :- %@ ",allIngrediantArr);

            NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateString];
            if (allIngrediantArr.count>0) {
                searchFilterdArr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[allIngrediantArr filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];
            }
```

Comment: show your tried code...

Comment: @Anbu.karthik please check now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the `searchFilterdArr` array by comparing the range of search string.

```
  NSString *searchStr = @"carrot";  
  NSArray *searchFilterdArr = [[NSArray alloc ] initWithObjects:@{@"title":@"baby carrot"},@{@"title":@"baby purple carrot"},@{@"title":@"carrot"}, nil];
  NSLog(@"%@",searchFilterdArr);
  id mySort = ^(NSDictionary * obj1, NSDictionary * obj2){
    return [[obj1 valueForKey:@"title"] rangeOfString:searchStr].location > [[obj2 valueForKey:@"title"] rangeOfString:searchStr].location;
  };
  NSArray * sortedMyObjects = [searchFilterdArr sortedArrayUsingComparator:mySort];
  NSLog(@"%@",sortedMyObjects);
```

searchFilterdArr

> {
>           title = "baby carrot";
>       },
>           {
>           title = "baby purple carrot";
>       },
>           {
>           title = "carrot";
>       }

sortedMyObjects

> {
>           title = "carrot";
>       },
>           {
>           title = "baby carrot";
>       },
>           {
>           title = "baby purple carrot";
>       }

Comment: I have a array if NSDictionaries not Array of Strings

Comment: @GurinderBatth Updated answer with NSDictionary

Comment: Yeah I am checking it and let you know

Comment: Thanks sir after little modifications its works for me

Answer (score 2):

you can use in the alternate

**BEGINSWITH**

```
predicateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELF.title BEGINSWITH [cd] \"%@\" ", tempString];
```

**CONTAINS || BEGINSWITH**

if you want the both (contains || Beginswith), then use

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                      @"(SELF.title BEGINSWITH [cd] \"%@\") OR (SELF.title CONTAINS [cd] \"%@\")", tempString, tempString];
```

**MATCHES || BEGINSWITH**

```
  NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                      @"(SELF.title BEGINSWITH [cd] \"%@\") OR (SELF.title MATCHES [cd] \"%@\")", tempString, tempString];
```

see the `NSPredicate` [string comparison](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html)

[image]

Comment: but i also need other results which contains that special word not only start with

Comment: @FahimParkar - hi my senior, how r u

Comment: @GurinderBatth - what the issue u faced , can you update the code

Comment: @GurinderBatth - if you update the ? its easy to understand